# Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR (I do have CREATOR)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parcelable

I am trying to pass Parcelable data from one intent to another and this is the error I am getting:

```
08-31 14:12:22.709: E/AndroidRuntime(9931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 14:12:22.709: E/AndroidRuntime(9931): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker/com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker.Igra}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker.Novaigra$Player
```

The thing is: I do have Parcelable.Creator object. I'll post the whole Parcelable code below:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable{
    String name;
    int score;
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(score);
    }

    public Player(Parcel source){
        score = source.readInt();
        name = source.readString();
    }

    public Player(int score, String name){
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MyCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<Player> {

    @Override
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Player(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }

}
```

Is there somethin wrong with the CREATOR? The app crashes as soon as I click the button to start the next activity.

This is how I "retrieve" Parcelable data in the second activity:

```
//global variable
ArrayList<Player> playersParceledData;

//This is in onCreate
playersData = getIntent();
playersParceledData = playersData.getParcelableArrayListExtra("parceledData");
```

Also, this is how I put class objects to ParcelableArrayListExtra:

```
Player newPlayer = new Player(0, text);
playersParceledData.add(newPlayer);
zacniIgro.putParcelableArrayListExtra("parceledData", playersParceledData);
```

Comment: I recommended to use ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> because it not requires to convert you can easily transfer between activities using getSeriasableExtra(). As i see your code you don't have any complex data to store in , so there is no meaning to crate a special POJO to store.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia could you please give me a quick example on how my code would look like with HashMap? I've never used that before and I can't really see how to use it from official docs.

Comment: your `player` class does not declare a static `CREATOR` member.  It only declares an implementation of the Creator class (`MyCreator`).  In addition to correcting the sequence, you would need to add the `CREATOR` member to `player`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are have different sequence when reading from Parcel than the one you write in.

In `writeToParcel()` you are first putting String but in the `HeatFriendDetail(Parcel in)`, you  first read integer. It is not the correct way because the order or read/write matters.

Following is the code which makes correct order when writing/reading the data to/from Parcel (also see [this link](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)):

```
public class FriendDetail implements Parcelable {

    private String full_name;
    private int privacy;

    public HeatFriendDetail(Parcel in) {
        this.full_name = in.readString();
        this.privacy = in.readInt();
    }

    public HeatFriendDetail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(this.full_name);
        dest.writeInt(this.privacy);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public HeatFriendDetail createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new HeatFriendDetail(in);
        }

        public HeatFriendDetail[] newArray(int size) {
            return new HeatFriendDetail[size];
        }
    };

    // GETTER SETTER//
}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker/com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker.Igra}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.matejsoftware.cardscoretracker.Novaigra$Player

Comment: this comment is a few years too late, but the OP's `Player` class is missing the required static member `public static Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new MyCreator();` (and it has also got the sequence wrong as correctly identified by this answer).  I add this comment now because none of the answers say this explicitly and the accepted answer works because it **does** declare CREATOR.

Answer (score 8):

I received this error in release apk only, because the CREATOR was not public.

I changed this :

```
static final Parcelable.Creator<Station> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Station>() {
```

To this :

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Station> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Station>() {
```

Comment: This is exactly what fixed my problem, weird because it's auto-generated without being public, do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this.

I had a hunch, and I looked in my ProGuard mapping file.

Normally I declare CREATOR like this:

```
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ClassA> CREATOR = 
            new Parcelable.Creator<ClassA>() {
```

which shows up in the mapping file like this:

```
    android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR -> CREATOR
```

..except for one class, the class that was reported with the error.  I declared it like this:

```
    public static Creator<ClassB> CREATOR =
            new Creator<ClassB>() {
```

Lo and behold:

```
    android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR -> a
```

So if you are getting this exception in your production release, check your mapping file.  I think ProGuard is really sensitive to how CREATOR is declared when deciding not to obfuscate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! I have been looking for this too long!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using proguard rules add this line in to your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error message when the CREATOR class was not static

Answer (score -2):

**Try this way**

```
// create List of player
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> players = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //create Player

        HashMap<String, String> player = new HashMap<String, String>();
        player.put("score", "20");//replace 20 with your score variable
        player.put("name", "Biraj");//replace Biraj with your name variable

        // Add to arraylist

        players.add(player);

        // pass to intent

        Intent i;
        i.putExtra("PLAYERS", players);

        // read From intent

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playerFromintent = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("PLAYERS");

        // read from ArrayList

        for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : playerFromintent) {
            System.out.println("Name : " + hashMap.get("name"));
            System.out.println("Score : " + hashMap.get("score"));
        }
```