# Write and Read an object array to parcelable

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson, parcelable

I have a JSON file that is being parsed with Gson.  The problem I have is there are nested arrays in the Json e.g.

```
"assets":[
      {
         "Address":"Crator1, The Moon",
         "Title":"The Moon",
         "AudioFile":null,
         "Categories":[
            {
               "CategoryName":"Restaurants",
               "Description":"blah blah",
               "ExternalLink":"",
               "File":"",
               "FileName":"0",
               "CategoryID":0,
               "ParentCategoryID":786,
               "Id":334,
               "Image":"",
            },
```

I know it's invalid, it's just for an example.  So based on previous questions I have asked and research I believe I should have my code as follows in order to parse the JSON correctly:

```
public class JsonAssets implements Parcelable{

    String Address;
    String Title;
    String AudioFile;
    Categories[] categories;


private class Categories{

    String CategoryName;
    String Description;
    String ExternalLink;
    String File;
    String FileName;
    int CategoryID;
    int ParentCategoryID;
    int Id;
    String Image;
}

 }
```

The class is passed as follows:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

reader.beginObject();
reader.nextName();
reader.beginArray();
JsonObject obj = null;


while (reader.hasNext()) {
    try{
        switch(type){
        case ASSET_UPDATE:
            obj = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonAsset.class);

            break;
        }
```

So I read and write the address, audio file as so:

```
  public static final Parcelable.Creator<AssetJson> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AssetJson>() {
        public AssetJson createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new AssetJson(in);
        }

        public AssetJson[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AssetJson[size];
  }
    };

public void writeToParcel(Parcel paramParcel, int paramInt) {

    paramParcel.writeString(Address);
    paramParcel.writeString(Title);
    paramParcel.writeString(AudioFile);
}

private JsonAsset(Parcel in) {

    Address = in.readString();
    Title = in.readString();
    AudioFile = in.readString();
}
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to read and write Categories[] to the parcel.  The fact that it is an object array has me stumped.

This is my first experience with parcelables and I'm trying to take over someone elses code.  So if anyone could explain how I would parcel an object array, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: go throught this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548077/parcelable-protocol-requires-a-parcelable-creator-object-called-creator-i-do-ha/18548274#18548274)

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani the issue with me doing that is the same as my reply to Techfist.  So I'm not sure where to go next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the correct solution (for me) so if anyone else is coming up against this, follow this link:
http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

It shows how to parse nested array and deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, first make your Category class implement Parcelable, implement all the logic for reading and writing back there, then use Parcel class `writeParcelableArray` method to write an array of parcelables.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for coming back to me, the problem with that approach is that I have already implemented parcelable in the assetJson class, I have edited my question to display this.  So the method  public static final Parcelable.Creator<ClassName> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ClassName>().  Cannot be duplicated as I have gotten the error 'variable CREATOR has already been defined'.  I had tried that route so I wasn't sure what to do.  I want to parcel the object array with the assetJson content.

Comment: So do you mean implement a Category class seperate to the assetJson class?  Not a subclass?

Comment: yes exactly, do that otherwise you wont be able to write that into parcel.