# implementing Parcelable in android, onRestoreInstanceState is not getting called

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Following is my class:

```
public class Line implements Parcelable {
    private Point start, end;

    public Line() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Line(Point start, Point end) {
        this.end = end;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Point getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Point start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(Point end) {
        this.end = end;
    } 
    @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

it contains two Point(`android.graphics.Point`) objects and i would like to implement parcelable in it, so that I can restore ArrayList of `Line` objects in `Activity`.

The problem as both my attributes are of type Point not sure how to write it in `writeToParcel` and read it in

```
public Line(Parcel in) {
        super();

    }
```

**EDIT**

following the answer I implemented the Line class. But in activity the problem is `onRestoreInstanceState` is never getting called.

When I press home button, and get back to the app all the data in my arrayLists is lost.

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putInt("player", player);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("lines", lines);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("rects1", rects1);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("rects2", rects2);
    // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    player = savedInstanceState.getInt("player");
    lines = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("lines");
    rects1 = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("rects1");
    rects2 = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("rects2");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem then? Can you explain?

Comment: `Point` already implements the Parcelable interface, so you can call `WriteToParcel()` on the points. Just make sure you read them out of a parcel in the same order as you wrote them to the parcel.

Comment: I am not sure how to read and write these objects to Parcel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
public class Line implements Parcelable {
    private Point start, end;

    public Line() {
    }

    public Line(Point start, Point end) {
        this.end = end;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Point getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Point start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(Point end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(start, flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(end, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0xDEAF;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Line> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Line>() {

        @Override
        public Line createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            Line line = new Line();
            Point start = source.readParcelable(Point.class.getClassLoader());
            Point end = source.readParcelable(Point.class.getClassLoader());
            line.setStart(start);
            line.setEnd(end);
            return line;
        }

        @Override
        public Line[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Line[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass the classloader for the `Point` class into the `source.readparcelable()` function? As you are reading out a `Point`, and not a `Line`.

Comment: @ThaMe90 here we can pass even `null` also. see the documentation `A ClassLoader from which to instantiate the Parcelable object, or null for the default class loader`

Comment: @Gopal Line class is not showing any error and I guess is save as well but the problem now is that on reStore is not getting call see my question again.

Comment: @vipulmittal `onRestoreInstanceState()` will be called only when you are changing the orientation. it will be not called when you press home button

Comment: so how to preserve my arraylists as when i press home come back to my app lists are empty

Comment: When you come back from the homescreen, the application goes trough the `onResume()` method (see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)).

Comment: @vipulmittal have you seen ThaMe90's comment?

Answer (score 0):

Use My [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548077/parcelable-protocol-requires-a-parcelable-creator-object-called-creator-i-do-ha/18548274#18548274).
you need to write all the values in writeToParcel method.
and create one Constructor and perform below steps.